# Oracle Linux 8 TFTP Server Failure

Tags: tftp, rhel8

I'm configuring a TFTP server on Oracle Linux 8 and running into some weird issues.

Configuration files:

```
/etc/systemd/system/tftp-server.service
::::::::::::::
[Unit]
Description=Tftp Server
Requires=tftp-server.socket
Documentation=man:in.tftpd

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/in.tftpd -c -p -s /tftpboot
StandardInput=socket

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=tftp-server.socket
::::::::::::::
/etc/systemd/system/tftp-server.socket
::::::::::::::
[Unit]
Description=Tftp Server Activation Socket

[Socket]
ListenDatagram=69
BindIPv6Only=both

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Both tftp-server and tftp.socket are running and enabled:

```
● tftp-server.service - Tftp Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tftp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-12-13 09:08:41 EST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:in.tftpd
 Main PID: 6308 (in.tftpd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 48835)
   Memory: 200.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/tftp-server.service
           └─6308 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -c -p -s /tftpboot

Dec 13 09:08:41 systemd[1]: Started Tftp Server.

● tftp.socket - Tftp Server Activation Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.socket; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-12-13 09:08:37 EST; 11min ago
   Listen: [::]:69 (Datagram)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 48835)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/tftp.socket

Dec 13 09:08:37 systemd[1]: Closed Tftp Server Activation Socket.
Dec 13 09:08:37 systemd[1]: Stopping Tftp Server Activation Socket.
Dec 13 09:08:37 systemd[1]: Listening on Tftp Server Activation Socket.
```

The /tftpboot directory permissions are set to world-readable (777) and there is a world-readable text file in the directory. When I attempt to TFTP from the same server, I get a "Error code 1: File not found". When I attempt a TFTP get from a server on the same local VLAN, the get starts and I eventually get a "Transfer timed out" error. The iptables on the server is configured to allow UDP port 69 inbound.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I followed the instructions at https://linuxhint.com/tftp_server_centos8/ but I simply cannot make a connection, even from the localhost. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out the issue. Running some status checks I noticed tftp and tftp-server were both running, but using different config files:

```
systemctl status tftp
● tftp.service - Tftp Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.service; indirect; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-12-14 10:56:41 EST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:in.tftpd
 Main PID: 9604 (in.tftpd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 48835)
   Memory: 244.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/tftp.service
           └─9604 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot

Dec 14 10:56:41 systemd[1]: Started Tftp Server.

systemctl status tftp-server
● tftp-server.service - Tftp Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tftp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2022-12-13 12:57:45 EST; 22h ago
     Docs: man:in.tftpd
 Main PID: 6832 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 13 12:42:45 systemd[1]: Stopped Tftp Server.
Dec 13 12:42:45 systemd[1]: Started Tftp Server.
Dec 13 12:57:45 systemd[1]: tftp-server.service: Succeeded.
```

Copying the syntax from /etc/systemd/system/tftp-server.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.service got TFTP working again. I'm not entirely clear why this happened, but at least TFTP is working now.